# Get rate from Future Value of Annuity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

$FV = \dfrac{(1+i)^t-1}{i}\cdot C$

What are the algabraic steps I need to rearrange to get i? The i divided by the i is specifically tripping me up.

Many thanks!

Comment: Sorry - was going off memory. Updated to change PV to C

Comment: What is $C$? The annual payment amount?

Comment: Cash flow per period

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, given $C$, $\text{FV}$, and $t$, we have
$$\dfrac{\text{FV}}{C}i=(1+i)^t-1$$
or $$1=\dfrac{\text{FV}}{C}i+(1+i)^t\text{.}$$
There is no way to write a (simple) formula for $i$ in this case for general $t$. Usually what is done is assuming you have the three variables, you would use a financial calculator, such as a BA-II+, to solve for $i$.

Comment: Sorry - I'm new to Math - what about the formula would indicate that there is no simple way to re-arrange for i? Is it because there is i over i? Just looking for a way of identifying myself in the future. Thanks!

Comment: @SebastianPatten There is no simple formula for $(1+i)^t$ and thus no way to isolate $i$.